# Вид папки по умолчанию в windows

Tags: windows, explorer

Как в windows выставить по умолчанию для папок:
<kbd>Вид</kbd> → <kbd>Таблица</kbd>

Comment: Вот [это](http://f1comp.ru/windows/windows-7-kak-sdelat-chto-by-v-papkax-fajly-otobrazhalis-ne-spiskom-a-obychnymi-znachkami/) подойдёт?

Answer (score 4):

1. Для текущей папки переключить вид на таблицу.
2. Нажать <kbd>Alt</kbd> - появится меню.
3. <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Folder Options</kbd>
4. Вторая вкладка <kbd>View</kbd>
5. Кнопка <kbd>Apply to folders</kbd>
6. Подтвердить